# simple Haskell module

Tags: haskell, module

Im trying to create an instance declaration for `ErrorOr a` so that values of any `ErrorOr a` can be compared against another using the `(==)` operator. Errors are never equivalent, even if they are identical; only results can be equivalent, and they are equivalent only if they are equal with respect to their own definition of equality.

```
*> ParseError "Test." == ParseError "Test."
False
*> Result 123 == Result 123
True
```

this is what was given:

```
module Error where

data ErrorOr a =
    Result a
  | ParseError String
  | TypeError String
  deriving Show

promote :: ErrorOr a -> ErrorOr b
promote (ParseError s     ) = ParseError s
promote (TypeError s      ) = TypeError s

instance Eq a => Eq (ErrorOr a) where
-- This is what I tried. and it doesn't work;(
Result x == Result y = x==y
ParseError q == ParseError w= q==w
TypeError s1 == TypeError s2 = s1==s2
_ == _ = False
```

Could somebody give a hint on how to do this?

I get the following error

```
Error.hs:15:25:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘==’
    It could refer to either ‘Error.==’, defined at Error.hs:15:10
                          or ‘Prelude.==’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at Error.hs:1:8-12
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Classes’)
```

Comment: `ErrorOr` is a *type constructor*; you can only pattern match on the *value constructors* (`Result`, `ParseError`, `TypeError`).

Comment: thank you! I just tried it...(updated the questions)

Comment: Indent the definition of the function `==` - it is inside the `instance` declaration, so it must be placed inside. The compiler believes you are defining a new `==` function independant of the `Eq` class because you have not indented it. Although if you want ParseErrors to never be equal, your code is not doing that. Simply remove the `ParseError` case and it will fall through to the default `False`, giving you the behaviour you want.

Comment: I think you want `False` to be the result when comparing `ParseError`s.

Comment: I suggest turning on `-Wall` while developing so you don't do weird stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is important in Haskell. It's how the compiler recognises where a block like an instance declaration ends.

In your case it ends immediately after the `where`, because the next line is not indented any more than the instance declaration. You've written an empty declaration, which is technically valid Haskell (because some classes have default definitions for all their methods), and then written another function which just happens to be called `==` but has no relation to the `==` that's part of the `Eq` class (hence you have two `==` in scope, so you get the ambiguous occurrence error).

You would get a warning about leaving the `Eq` instance empty, but the error might be hiding the warning.

As an aside, having your error values never compare equal might not be the best idea. Equality relationships (which `Eq` is intended to represent) must be:

1. reflexive - a thing is always equal to itself
2. symmetric - if `a == b` then also `b == a`
3. transitive - if `a == b` and `b == c` then also `a == c`

Having `ParseError _ /= ParseError _` breaks reflexivity (`let e = ParseError "not reflexive" in e == e`).

Library code that uses `Eq` generically usually assumes those three properties. An example would be comparison-based containers like `Map` and `Set` (although these need `Ord` as well); you would find these behave quite strangely on your `ErrorOr` values.